# How to filter the GROUP_CONCAT in my SELECT

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I am trying to SELECT (all of the multiple) comments from Wordpress which relate to a post (wp_comments.comment_content) with GROUP_CONCAT but I only want to select those comments which DON'T contain the text string "status". If there are no comments at all, or only comments which contain "status" I still want to see those records in the result, just without getting anything back for *comments*.

When I tried putting a condition similar to [WHERE wp_comments.comment_content NOT LIKE "%status%"] at the end of the complete query, records which only have a comment containing "status" don't display AT ALL, I still need to get those records, just without the comments.

I want to try something like the below version but this throws up an error and doesn't spit out any data at all. (The overall query works as expected btw apart from the comment selection section..).

Maybe I am joining the wp_comments table in the wrong place, using the wrong join, not using a properly formatted nested SELECT or similar, maybe it needs a separate SELECT at the end so I can get the comments back I want in a way which doesn't effect which records are selected overall.. not sure..

Any idea what I am doing wrong or how to approach this?

Here is my query, thanks in advance for any kind pointers!

```
select wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value as firstwoometavalue, 
wp_postmeta.meta_value as firstwpmetavalue, Y.meta_value as ymetavalue, 
Z.meta_value as zmetavalue, X.meta_value as xmetavalue, 
(GROUP_CONCAT(wp_comments.comment_content) as commentcontent 
WHERE wp_comments.comment_type = "order_note" AND 
wp_comments.comment_content NOT LIKE "%status%")
FROM wp_postmeta 
left JOIN wp_postmeta as Y
ON wp_postmeta.post_id = Y.post_id
left JOIN wp_posts
ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID
left JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items
ON wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_id = wp_posts.ID
left JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta
ON wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id = wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id
left JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta as Z
ON wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id = Z.order_item_id
left JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta as X
ON wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id = X.order_item_id
left JOIN wp_comments
ON wp_comments.comment_post_ID = wp_posts.ID
where 1=1
AND wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_key ="Adults"
AND wp_postmeta.meta_key ="_billing_first_name"
AND Y.meta_key ="_billing_last_name"
AND Z.meta_key ="Booking Type"
AND Z.meta_value LIKE "%'.$showlocation.'%"
AND X.meta_key ="Booking Date"
AND X.meta_value = "'.$showdate.'"
AND wp_posts.post_status ="wc-completed" 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
 SELECT 
wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value AS Adults,
wp_postmeta.meta_value AS FirstName,
jn_postmeta_lastname.meta_value AS LastName,
jn_woocommerce_order_itemmeta_location.meta_value AS Location,
jn_woocommerce_order_itemmeta_date.meta_value AS ShowDate,
(SELECT 
        GROUP_CONCAT(wp_comments.comment_content)
    FROM
        wp_comments
    WHERE
        wp_comments.comment_content NOT LIKE '%status%'
            AND wp_comments.comment_post_ID = wp_posts.ID) Notes
 FROM
wp_postmeta
    LEFT JOIN
wp_postmeta AS jn_postmeta_lastname ON wp_postmeta.post_id = jn_postmeta_lastname.post_id
    LEFT JOIN
wp_posts ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID
    LEFT JOIN
wp_woocommerce_order_items ON wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_id = wp_posts.ID
    LEFT JOIN
wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta ON wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id = wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id
    LEFT JOIN
wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS jn_woocommerce_order_itemmeta_location ON wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id = jn_woocommerce_order_itemmeta_location.order_item_id
    LEFT JOIN
wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS jn_woocommerce_order_itemmeta_date ON wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id = jn_woocommerce_order_itemmeta_date.order_item_id
    LEFT JOIN
wp_comments ON wp_comments.comment_post_ID = wp_posts.ID
WHERE
1 = 1
    AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_billing_first_name'
    AND jn_postmeta_lastname.meta_key = '_billing_last_name'
    AND wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_key = 'Adults'
    AND jn_woocommerce_order_itemmeta_location.meta_key = 'Booking Type'
    AND jn_woocommerce_order_itemmeta_location.meta_value LIKE "%'.$showlocation.'%"
    AND jn_woocommerce_order_itemmeta_date.meta_key = 'Booking Date'
    AND jn_woocommerce_order_itemmeta_date.meta_value = "'.$showdate.'"
    AND wp_posts.post_status = 'wc-completed'
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
```